# Clear Redis-Cli history on Windows machine

Tags: redis, redis-cli

Every time i open Redis-Cli tool , I can see my past entered commands including passwords.

How can i clear the history of Redis-Cli

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the history to be kept in `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.rediscli_history` file at all - you can set the environment variable `REDISCLI_HISTFILE=/dev/null` and it will prevent the history to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the Redis-Cli History follow the instructions below:

1- Goto folder "C:\Users[username]"

2- Clear the content of the file ".rediscli_history"